# Lose of Power when Headlights On and Accelerating

Tags: electrical, nissan, power-loss

I have a Nissan Navara D40 2013, I install some aftermarkets headlights that has projector so I can use legally my HIDs, but after 2 weeks of installing this aftermarket headlights when I have the engine running and I want to move I put first gear and if I have the lights on the truck loses the power and I have all my foot out of the clutch and the accelerator is floored but I sudden shut off the lights switch the power comes back, or when I have the lights on and change the gear to second, the power comes right back, what could be causing this, I have been 3 times last week on the mechanic and didnt find out whats happening. [image: This is my truck]
P.D: I own the truck since new.

**UPDATE (Jan. 7): Change the tailights bulbs to the normal ones from the LED it had installed and problem was cause due to one LED that broke. **

Comment: Aftermarket alterations are difficult to help with, because we have no idea if everything is installed properly. Considering this only happens when the lights are powered on, I would suspect something is shorted out, or improperly connected. It might be a good idea to have the alternator / charging system checked for proper operation with the lights off and while on. Then determine if your lights are drawing more amperage than the alternator is able to put out?